# Fireworks - Delete color from specific pixel color

Tags: fireworks

[image]

From that picture I want to delete all instances of that specific color without having to go manually each pixel at a time.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use *Select / Select Similar* to get a selection of all of the pixels with that colour, but bear in mind that *Select Similar* is affected by the Tolerance setting of the Magic Wand (W) tool.

So, first select the Magic Wand and set the tolerance to zero, then select one of the pixels you want to delete (with Marquee (M) and Edge set to Hard for example), then run *Select / Select Similar*. You can use the Paint Bucket (G) to replace the selection with whatever colour you want.

Of course, if you do want to catch pixels which aren't exactly the same colour, you can just set the Tolerance slightly higher.